# How to install nautilus-terminal in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: command-line, nautilus, gnome-terminal

I recently upgraded to Raring 13.04 and am having trouble installing nautilus-terminal http://projects.flogisoft.com/nautilus-terminal/

I rely very heavily on the project and how feel handicapped without the little terminal above my nautilus.

I have installed the application successfully but I think the new version of Nautilus does not support this plugin. Please correct me if im wrong.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nautilus-terminal is not compatible with the version of Nautilus installed by default in Ubuntu 13.04.

From the [link](http://projects.flogisoft.com/nautilus-terminal/) you provided:

> Compatibility with Nautilus:
>
> Nautilus Terminal 1.0 works with Nautilus 3.0 and 3.2
>   Nautilus Terminal 0.7.1 and previous work only with Nautilus 2.2x and Nautilus 2.3x

The version of Nautilus available by default in Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring) is 3.6.3 ([link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nautilus&searchon=names&suite=raring&section=all))

You'll need to downgrade Nautilus (which could very well be a highly involved task due to dependencies) or use a separate terminal window.  For your purposes, [tilda](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tilda&searchon=names&suite=raring&section=all) or [guake](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=guake&searchon=names&suite=raring&section=all) may be a decent stand-in until Nautilus-terminal is updated to support Nautilus-3.6.x.

NOTE: I'd link to tilda and guake, but I don't have at least 10 reputation yet.

I hope that helps you out.

EDIT: Updated to add links for tilda and guake since reputation gain.

Comment: @cyberjar09 No problem!

Comment: nautilus-terminal 1.0 is actually works in 3.x for now(mine is 3.10.1 and works). Just follow [this page](https://launchpad.net/nautilus-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/nautilus-terminal-10-released-with.html

Try the method on this link. It wasnt working on mine as well. This helped me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: it did not work for me.